# SharePoint 2016 on premise asking for credentials for 1 specific site

Tags: 2016, credentials

SharePoint 2016 on premise with Office 2016. This issue suddenly came up a week ago with no changes with permissions or configuration changes on Central Admin for only 3 users. We have hundreds of other users who don't have this issue. We have like 100 site collections.

We have 1 site and beneath a subsite with unique permissions. On this subsite there are several libraries and 1 library has unique permissions on it. With this setup the user can't see the (sub)site but can go directly to the library with a link. Till a week ago the user can open Word files just fine but now SharePoint suddenly asks for credentials after opening a Word file. Another strange thing what i see is when the user opens the library with explorer, this window shows no documents.

What have i tested/concluded:

-I created a new library with unique permissions on the same subsite and the credentials screen comes up when try opening Word documents.
-I created a new test site with the same setup so 1 site and beneath a subsite with unique permissions plus a library with unique permissions. The user can't see the (sub)site which is what we want and the documents can be opened without the credentials screen when going to the library! - I concluded that the issue isn't caused by a document itself.

- I gave the user a whole new Windows profile. No result
- I removed all the unique permissions on the subsite and library and put them back again. No result
- I removed the user from the site collection and added the user again. No result
- I gave the user permission for the subsite which **solves the problem** but the user then can see the subsite content and the other libraries which is what we don't want.
- Our Office apps doesn't allow users to log in with other accounts. This feature is turned off.
- ISS Windows Authentication is Enabled.
- Changing the library setting "Default open behavior for browser-enabled documents" to "Open in the client application" has no result.

My conclusion is that this only happens to 3 users on 1 specific site collection and that somehow the credentials are not passed on correctly. I can not really figure out in what direction i should look for a solution. Any ideas?

Comment: So the setup is this:

We have 1 site and beneath a subsite with unique permissions. On this subsite there are several libraries and 1 library has unique permissions on it. With this setup the user can't see the (sub)site but can go directly to the library with a link.

The user will get "limited access" on the site to be able to go directly to the library. I have temporarily solved the issue by changing "limited access" into "Restricted Interfaces for Translation". Not the ideal solution but the credentials pop-up screen doesn't appear now.

Answer (score 0):

So the setup is this:

*We have 1 site and beneath a subsite with unique permissions. On this subsite there are several libraries and 1 library has unique permissions on it. With this setup the user can't see the (sub)site but can go directly to the library with a link.*

The user will get "limited access" on the site to be able to go directly to the library. I have temporarily solved the issue by changing "limited access" into "Restricted Interfaces for Translation". Not the ideal solution but the credentials pop-up screen doesn't appear now.